# Value should be string- Invalid argument e2e test

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am running a e2e test for an angular application by protractor, but I am getting the following error when running the test for a feature file

Value in UI which I am checking is -WORKSCOPES (2239)

Code for the steps in steps.js:

```
this.Then(/^I get the workscope count$/, (callback) => {  
        
            workscopeUtil.getTextUsingTestHelperPo('div[class="new-workscope-header col-12 col-md-12 mt-3 mb-3"]').then(actualVal => {                  
            wsCountBeforeReset = actualVal.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
            console.log('workscopeCount :'+wsCountBeforeReset);
            callback();
        });
    });
```

---

Error when running the feature file test is :

Failures:

```
1) Scenario: US13241:1of1 Search with ESN and results should be displayed in a carousel - Test_Modules\Workscope\Features\WorkscopeSearch.feature:24
   Step: And I get the workscope count - Test_Modules\Workscope\Features\WorkscopeSearch.feature:8
   Step Definition: Test_Modules\Workscope\step_definitions\WorkscopeAdditionalFilters_Steps.js:262
   Message:
     WebDriverError: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
       (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
       (Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.14 (be04594a2b8411758b860104bc0a1033417178be-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#119}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
         at WebDriverError (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27:5)
         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)
         at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:360:15
         at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
         at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
         at asyncRun (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27)
         at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
     From: Task: <anonymous>
         at pollCondition (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2236:16)
         at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2232:9
         at new Promise (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1043:7)
         at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2231:14
         at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
         at asyncRun (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2697:25)
         at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
     From: Task: <anonymous wait>
         at ControlFlow.wait (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2229:17)
         at Driver.wait (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:688:29)
         at Protractor.to.(anonymous function) [as wait] (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\protractor.js:55:29)
         at World.When (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\Test_Modules\Workscope\step_definitions\WorkscopeSearch_Steps.js:159:17)
         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with async await, this should work it actually working fine (I have no idea about the deep logic in your application here)

```
it("I get the workscope count", async () => {  
        const actualVal = await workscopeUtil.getTextUsingTestHelperPo('div[class="new-workscope-header col-12 col-md-12 mt-3 mb-3"]');
           
        wsCountBeforeReset = actualVal.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
        console.log('workscopeCount :'+wsCountBeforeReset);
    });
```

please add kind of `expect(....)` here otherwise test shows as skip